# How do I send a EHLO/HELO command from my email client in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm using the Swiftmailer lib and I'm getting a weird error "expected code 250 but received code 501 5.5.4 invalid domain name" and I think it's related to my client not sending an EHLO command to our exchange server. How do I send an EHLO to our exchange server to initiate SMTP for an email client?

Comment: Consult with your mail server administrator about why your request was rejected.

Comment: Swiftmailer should be doing that for you

Comment: @Dagon that's what I thought but I have no other idea why I would be getting the error I'm getting.